# Spring's @Value not working correctly when in CamelConfiguration subclass

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-java-config

I noticed a strange behaviour when using `@Value` with `CamelConfiguration`

Having an example properties file:

```
test.list=foo,bar,baz
```

and  having a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, a ConversionService and when referencing the property in some regular Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:example.properties")
public class RegularConfig {

    @Value("${test.list}")
    List<String> testList;

}
```

Everything works as intended (`testList` contains three values: `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`), but when the configuration class extends `org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:example.properties")
public class RegularConfig extends CamelConfiguration {

    @Value("${test.list}")
    List<String> testList;

}
```

(see minimal running example for both cases at https://github.com/michalmela/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/35719697)

the `testList` contains one, joined value: `foo,bar,baz`.

Is this a misconfiguration on my side? Or some kind of bug (or feature)?

(I know the obvious workaround is to split the values manually, which is what I already went with, but I'd just like to understand what is going on here)

Comment: Have you added a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean to your spring config? Not sure if this will add the split vlaues to the list though

Comment: Yes, there is one. I have an extended implementation of it which is logging all resolutions and I can see the value being resolved twice, with the same value, by the same `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. I suspect there is something wrong with `PropertySourcesPropertyResolver`'s `conversionService`, but I am not sure (for now I switched to resolving the value to a simple string and manually splitting it)

Comment: I tried your sample code but have not faced any problems.  My sample can be downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/35719697).  What Spring and Camel versions are you using?  @Alberto's answer below is also correct in that you will not get a `List` without using SpEL with Spring 4.x but then you may be using a different version.

Comment: You are right, the full example required some additional configuration: firstly, a `conversionService` configured, secondly, a base context (because apparently `conversionService` won't work in the same java-config context it was set up in). I uploaded a running example to https://github.com/michalmela/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/35719697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CamelConfiguration` declare a `BeanPostProcessor` (`camelBeanPostProcessor`). BeanPostProcessor-s are instantiated by spring at first (because they have to see all others beans instantiation).

When Spring instantiate this `camelBeanPostProcessor`, it creates an instance of your class extending `CamelConfiguration`, inject the properties, and invoke `camelBeanPostProcessor()`.

So, properties injected in this instance are injected at the beginning of the Spring ApplicationContext initialization. At this time, your `ConversionService` is not yet registered: The default converter is used, instead of the `StringToCollectionConverter`.

As a workaround, you can register explicitly a `ConversionService` before refreshing the applicationContext :

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctxt.getBeanFactory().setConversionService(new DefaultConversionService());
ctxt.register(...);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was well aware of how `BeanPostProcessor`-s work but didn't manage to connect the dots myself (and I feel stupid lol). At least now I know that what I assumed was an ugly workaround is actually pretty valid solution.

Comment: Honestly, I think too it's an ugly hack ;-) But I don't know a better workaround!

Comment: Ah, no, I meant splitting the value by hand with `org.springframework.util.StringUtils#commaDelimitedListToStringArray` (which is what the default converter would do underneath). In fact so far I have only one such value so now it makes sense to me to just do it that way instead of manually injecting conversion service.

Answer (score -1):

I know it may sound stupid but are you sure the configuration worked correctly before extending CamelConfiguration class? It doesn't look to me that @Value without using SpEL will split the list. I would use this configuration

```
@Value(value = "#{'${test.list}'.split(',')}")
```

Which version of Spring are you using?. Thanks

Comment: In fact I am using the same property in two separate configurations and it still works great in the second one.Looking over property resolver code it seems to do have relevant facilities to read a list from the property: `StringToCollectionConverter`, which is within default `conversionService` configuration, does exactly that. It also works when using `environment.getProperty("someKey", List.class)` (although it leaves you with a generic `List`, not a `List<String>`, which doesn't really matter in such a trivial case but IDE complains about that...)

Comment: I can't help then. I've never worked with that 'problematic' class and I can't see anything in its documentation that explains the issue. Your suspect on the conversionService looks right though.

Comment: Thank you for your interest though. I had to move on with a workaround for now but the issue was strange enough to make me ask about it. I will try to put up a minimal runnable test application as soon as I have some free time.